# How to match a strings with 1 digit and 4 letters that one letter repeat exactly twice and the rest different from each other

Tags: python, regex

I need regex to match a word with length of 5 that contains 1 digit (`0-9`) and 4 small letters (`a-z`) but one of the letters repeat **exactly** twice and the **rest** are **different** from each other.

Example for **correct** match:

```
aa1bc  
2adba  
v4alv
```

Example for **wrong** match:

```
aa1bbc   => notice that although one letter (a) repeat twice,
            other letters are not different from each other (bb)  
1aaaa  
b3ksl
```

I used `^(?=.{5}$)[a-z]*(?:\d[a-z]*)(.*(.).*\1){1}$` to match all the words that contains 1 digit and 4 letters but I don't know how to make sure that only one letter repeat exactly twice and the rest are different.

Comment: Why does it have to be regex?

Comment: Have you not already asked this question?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness it was regarding groups. Now I want to know about specific group.

Comment: @zvone Because I have recursive script that provide me all the combinations of words with 1 digit and 4 letters and I want to extract this specific pattern. I think it can be faster than writing a script that will do it.

Comment: I don't see how a regex would be faster than a function which does this. It would be faster, more readable, and much easier to implement.

Comment: @zvone I have 3,920,000 combinations, so moving each word and inside each word check each char sounds that it will take more time than using a regex template.

Comment: I did not say you should make 3,920,000 combinations, I said you should not use a regex. Those are not the only two options that exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a `dictionary` to keep track of frequencies of each `character` of the `string`

**(comments inline)**

```
def is_it_correct(inp):
    if(len(inp) != 5):
        return False
    # store characters in a dictionary; key=ASCII of a character, value=it's frequency in the input string
    ind = 0
    dictionary = dict()
    while(ind < len(inp)):
        cur_char = inp[ind]
        cur_int = ord(cur_char)
        if(dictionary.get(cur_int) == None):
            dictionary[cur_int] = 1
        else:
            dictionary[cur_int] = dictionary[cur_int]+1
        ind = ind+1
    # Make sure there's only one digit (0-9) i.e ASCII b/w 48 & 57
    # Also, make sure that there are exactly 4 lower case alphabets (a-z) i.e ASCII b/w 97 & 122
    digits = 0
    alphabets = 0
    for key, val in dictionary.items():
        if(key >= 48 and key <= 57):
            digits = digits+val
        if(key >= 97 and key <= 122):
            alphabets = alphabets+val
    if(digits != 1 or alphabets != 4):
        return False
    # you should have 4 distinct ASCII values as your dictionary keys (only one ASCII is repeating in 5-length string)
    if(len(dictionary) != 4):
        return False
    return True

ret = is_it_correct("b3ksl")
print(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, you don't need regex for this:

```
>>> import random,string
>>> l=random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,4)
>>> l.append(str(random.randint(0,10)))
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> ''.join(l)
'iNx1k'
>>>
```

Or if want more:

```
import random,string
lst=[]
for i in range(3):
    l=random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,4)
    l.append(str(random.randint(0,10)))
    random.shuffle(l)
    lst.append(''.join(l))
```

#### Update:

```
import random,string
lst=[]
for i in range(3):
    l=random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,4)
    l[-1]=l[0]
    l.append(str(random.randint(0,10)))
    random.shuffle(l)
    lst.append(''.join(l))
print(lst)
```

## To answer yours:

```
import re
def check(val):
    return len(set(val))!=len(val) and len(re.sub('\d+','',val)) and val.islower() and len(val)==5
a = check("a1abc")
print(a)
```

Comment: But I have large list of words: `aab2b`, `a1clg`, `alda2`, etc. and I need to find who has repeating letter where the other are different. I don't understand how your code is helping me. I just generate random strings.

Comment: @E235 Edited mine

Comment: this is not what I meant. Your code is just generating string not related to my question. I specified that the match should be only on strings that has one letter that repeating twice and the rest are different: `aba1c`, `dkld2`, etc.

Comment: @E235 Okay understand but why need a downvote for this

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question. Anyway, I took it back.

Comment: @E235 Edited mine

Comment: This post does not answer the question, but rather creates new strings which is not OP's intention

Comment: Downvote? If i were to do so i would have done it an hour ago.

Comment: although you need to update it in order to answer the question

Comment: @Onyambu Oh yeah, form the other post i relize my problem